# How do I specify my extension is an 'app' in the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

I've made a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-tasks/bngpflcpbefndiblbdjokgpmbldcoplk) and set a browser_action in my manifest. This puts a little icon in the browser bar, and then clicking that runs background.js which opens the app in a new tab.

However, I notice that on the web store, my app icon is listed inside a little jigsaw piece, and it doesn't appear on the [Chrome New Tab page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95451) like other 'apps' I've installed.

Do I need to set something specific in my manifest.json file for it to be listed as an 'app' instead of an extension? Is there any benefit to even making it an app apart from removing the jigsaw piece and having it listed on the new tab page?

Here's my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "name": "Super Simple Tasks",
  "description": "A very simple tasks app that uses localStorage.",
  "version": "1.1",

  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],

  "offline_enabled": true,

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "Super Simple Tasks"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that it is an `app`:

`"app": {...},`

This will explain how to format your manifest: https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/manifest.html